# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient throws continuously error 404

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient

I'm trying to use the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class but it keeps throwing me an 404 error, even if I try the code from the doc :

```
var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/datalist.aspx");
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

try
{
    var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    Debug.WriteLine("content : {0}", result);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("error : {0}", e.Message);
}
```

And this is the error :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
error : Not found (404).

Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

[link of the doc I used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx)

I can access the address from the phone with a web browser like IE.

Comment: Perhaps the url you are trying to access checks specific headers?  Visit that page while Fiddler is running and mimic the headers in your code.

Comment: It should return 404, the fact that you can browse to an URL in a webbrowser does not guarantee it returns 200 or another "OK" status code.

If you go to the url with a HTTP sniffer like Fiddler running you will see the server returns 404 when navigating to this URL while still sending a response body.

Comment: Yes, that the mistake I made. I just checked with web browser in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it does return a `404` (use a sniffer and check).

Change the url to `http://www.example.com` and things will work.

The site returns the same response on all requests. You can try:

```
http://www.example.com/mynickistuff.abcd
```